# MySQL & jQuery: Store dynamic generated content in database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a dynamic form that creates some inputs that will generate values and should be saved into the database. Each set of values should be saved separetely in a single field in the database called "Education":

Should be stored like this:

```
+--------+---------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----+
|   id   |  name   |  Education                                         |
+--------+---------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----+
|  100   |  John   |  [Harvard, Marketing,2009,2014] [MIT,CS,2005,2009] |
+--------+---------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----+
|  101   | Daniel  |  [TEC, Marketing,2009,2014] [Standford,CS,2001,2005]|
+--------+---------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----+
```

The Education field can have up to 10 sets of values, I'm just showing 2.

**Please look at the JSFIDDLE to see how it actually works:** http://jsfiddle.net/YueX2/6/

- How can I store into the database when a single set of values is edited and saving it into the database only updating the given set of values?
- Also, is this the best way to do it?

Comment: The solution has two or even three very distinct parts. First, you need to store data in a database using PHP. Javascript/JQuery cannot write to your database directly. Then you should post the form data to PHP. You can do that without Javascript first. If that works, you can make the form 'Ajax enhanced', so the data is posted in the background and the result is used to update the page. Over all, this question is both to broad and a duplicate. This has been discussed countless times before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save data into database using jquery and json in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20720011/how-to-save-data-into-database-using-jquery-and-json-in-asp-net)

Comment: True, this is a multi-faceted question.  You would need some server-side language to go along with this and know how to access a database in that language.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks for you answer, but why are you saying it's a possible duplicate? It's not even the same question nor same code, etc. If you look closely, you can see that is not a duplicate.

Comment: The most important thing to note about your table design is that it is not in first normal form (1NF). In 1NF, every cell in a database contains 1 and only 1 value. They are 'atomic'. That's why everybody below is recommending you split it up. Take a look here: http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a practice in designing databases called normalization which would lead you to the best way to go about it.  Based on your Question and jsFiddle you would end up with 2 separate database tables.

Ex: `tbl_Users`: which would contain fields such as

```
userID
userName
```

Then you would have another table Ex: `tbl_Education` which would contain a few fields such as

```
record_id
userID
schoolName
```

It is in this table where you would set the particular users id in the `userID` field which would have to match the `userID` field from `tbl_Users` and then a single school they attended in the `schoolName` field.  If they attended multiple schools, they would have multiple entries in the `tbl_Education` table but only a single entry in the `tbl_Users` table.  If you need to retrieve the data you would perform a SQL query on the two table and `join` on the `User_id` field.  This would result in multiple records being returned, but with all of the data needed.

Any information which is specific to the particular part of their education would go in the `tbl_Education` table and anything specific to the user (hair color, eye color, height, etc) would go in the `tbl_Users` table.

Ex SQL Query:

```
SELECT tbl_Users.userID, tbl_Users.userName, tbl_Education.schoolName
FROM tbl_Users, tbl_Education
WHERE tbl_Users.userID = tbl_Education.userID;
```

The WHERE clause is essentially the join between the two tables.  There are many ways to write this query, I used the method which seems visually the easiest to see what is going on.

Here is the wikipedia link for normalization to get you started. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: I wasn't sure how to do it and I thought my way was better, thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

This is not the best way to solve this problem. You better make 2 tables.

Table users:

```
+--------+---------+
|   id   |  name   |
+--------+---------+
```

Table education:

```
+--------+----------+------------+-------+-----+------+
|   id   | location | discipline | start | end | user |
+--------+----------+------------+-------+-----+------+
```

As education.user you save a foreign key users.id from the user table. the implementation of the input form is on the one hand side more complex but you have no limitations of entrys per user nor too much overhead in your database.